# How to use the new Subsonic 3.0 IRepository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, subsonic

Can someone (hopefully Rob) explain how to implement the new SubSonicRepository<> Pattern?  I have used it with the old version and the MVC templates (in web forms) using the following initialization.

```
    public IRepository<StaffingPosition> _StaffingPositionsRepository;

    public  StaffingBase()
    {
        _StaffingPositionsRepository = new SubSonicRepository<StaffingPosition>();
    }
    public StaffingBase(IRepository<StaffingPosition> staffingpositionsRepo)
    {
        _StaffingPositionsRepository = staffingpositionsRepo;
    }
```

Note that my WCF Service inherits this class for ease of access.
Now SubSonicRepository() requires an argument of IQuerySurface and I'm not sure the best way to make this happen.  I really dig the IRepository pattern and want to try to stick with it if possible...That is, unless anyone has better ideas.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The templates generate a new class that implement IQuerySurface, the name of which you can configure in the main .tt file (usually something like NorthwindDb). Usually all that is needed is to pass a new instance of this class to the repository:

```
_StaffingPositionsRepository = new SubSonicRepository<StaffingPosition>(new StaffingDB());
```

Comment: This worked! That being said, whenever I use the new Subonic, even in this case, it returns the correct number of records but all the record items, in this case a generic list, are null.  Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: You should post this as a new questions with more details. You'll get a lot more responses that way.